# How does Cache-Control effect in Request header, compared with in Response header

Tags: http, http-headers

I know that if I got a response contains a header `Cache-Control:max-age=100`,that means the freshness lifetime of cache is 100 seconds. Does that mean in the 100 seconds, subsequent requests will never request to server? All these requests just receive a response in cache?

Therefore I have a question ,if the subsequent request contains a header `Cache-Control:no-cache` or `Cache-Control:max-age=0`, will it request to the original server in the 100 seconds even if the cache is not stale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does that mean in the 100 seconds, subsequent requests will never request to server? All these requests just receive a response in cache?**

Unless subsequent requests use `Cache-Control` header for more control on cache, Yes, the requests will just get response data from cache.

**If the subsequent request contains a header `Cache-Control:no-cache` or `Cache-Control:max-age=0`, will it request to the original server in the 100 seconds even if the cache is not stale?**

Yes, it will send HTTP request to original server. `Cache-Control:no-cache` in request header means: "unless the resource is re-validated, browser won't accept it from cache". `Cache-Control:max-age=<n>` in request header means: "browser won't accept any cache longer than *n* seconds" -- when *n* is 0, browser will always send request to server.

Here is a simple experiment.

In browser:

```
var poll = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/poll',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      //xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      //xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
    },
    success: function(){
      setTimeout(poll, 5000);
    }
  });
}
poll();
```

In server:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  ...
  // if request path is /poll
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=18');
  res.end();
})
```

You can observe that:

1. When `/poll` request does not contain `Cache-Control` header, browser will send request to origin server, fetch resource from cache for the next 3 requests, and then send request to origin server again...
2. When `/poll` request has 'Cache-Control' header as `no-cache` or `max-age=0`, browser will always send request to origin server.

Please note when this experiment is executed on Chrome, you need to un-check `Disable cache` in the DevTool.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is awesome!

Comment: @Squirtle.F is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?